# basic java program questions

Tags: java

```
public class A { //some fields (may not only primitive types) and methods here}

   public class B {// some fields (may not only primitive types) and methods here, may also have a class A reference }
```

Questions are followed :

```
    public class Test{ 

public static void main(String[] args){ 

A a = new A();//1. it will allocate memory for one object of A and a is the reference points to that space? 

ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>(10);//2. it will allocate memory for 10 objects of B?

ArrayList<B> bList2 = bList;//3. bList2 reference to the same location as bList?

ArrayList<B> bList3 = new ArrayList<B>(20);//4. bList3 points to a memory location which can hold 20 objects of B?

bList3 = bList;//5. bList3 now points to the same location as bList, and the space allocated in question 4 will be cleaned by  garbage collector later?

ArrayList<B> bList4 = new ArrayList<B>(10);
bList4.addAll(bList);//6. it is the same as bList4 = bList;? and the memory created in above line will be cleaned by garbage collector later?

method1(bList3);//7.after this function call bList3 will point to memory space created for bLista inside the method1? and we can modify the content of that space via bList3

} 

public void method1(ArrayList<B> list){
//do something here
ArrayList<B> bLista = new ArrayList<B>();
list = bLista;
}

}
```

Comment: Surely most of these questions are things you can easily test by running the code and checking where the references point.  Why ask when you can experiment?

Comment: I don't think you can meaningfully "check where the references point" and correctly understand the results unless you already have a basic understanding what references and objects *are* and what the difference between them is - which is exactly what the OP is apparently lacking and trying to get a grip on through these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No.
3. Yes.
4. Sort of. Not really. Is this a trick question?
5. Yes!
6. No.
7. No.

Okay, here are some real answers.

1. The `new` operator allocates memory unless there isn't enough available. Even if the constructor of the object fails, and the allocated memory is quickly garbage collected, room for the new object is allocated temporarily.
2. This allocates space for the fields of an `ArrayList`, which don't depend on the number of elements in the `ArrayList`, and in addition, it will create enough space for references to 10 objects, which don't depend on the size of the objects themselves; the pointers will be 32 bits on a 32-bit system, and 64 bits (or maybe compressed to something less by a really smart VM someday) on a 64-bit system.
3. This is a simple assignment. Both variables have been assigned the same value.
4. Memory has been allocated initially for 20 object references. However, if more than 20 objects are added to the list, `ArrayList` will automatically reallocate the necessary storage.
5. Yes. In this case, one can see that no references to the object originally assigned to `bList3` can "escape" to be strongly referenced. That unreferenced object is now eligible for garbage collection.
6. `bList4` still points to the same object, and that object cannot be garbage collected. That list references all the elements referenced by `bList`, but they aren't the same. In particular, changes to one list won't affect the other, but changes to the *contents* of the lists will be visible through either list.
7. No, Java passes references by value, so a method can't cause a caller's reference to refer to a different object.

Comment: B[] bArray = new B[10]; is the same as ArrayList<B> = new ArrayList<B>() which only allocate space for references but not for objects?

Comment: They are similar; when you create an object array (like creating an `ArrayList`), the space required for the array itself depends only on the system you are running. It is completely independent of the component type of the array. `new ReallyHugeObject[10]` allocates the same amount of memory as new ReallyTinyObject[10]`—enough for 10 object references.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. No. It will allocate memory for 10 *references* to B objects, and possibly more (since ArrayList can grow and have more space internally than is currently needed for its contents).
3. Yes.
4. See 2.
5. Yes.
6. No. You created two separate `ArrayList` objects in this case, meaning that if you add another element to `bList4` or remove one of its elements, the change will not be visible in `bList` and vice versa (which it would if you assigned `bList4 = bList;`
7. No, because you overwrite a *copy* of the reference `bList3` inside `method1` - which has no effect outside the method. If, however, you modified the list object or its contents, the changes would be visible outside.